# Can you offset map.getCenter with padding?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In Mapbox you can use [setCenter](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setcenter) with an optional "padding" value which is useful for offsetting the map center if there are things such as overlays on part of the map. However [getCenter](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#getcenter) does not seem to have the same padding option. This becomes an issue when I need to get the map center that matches the visual location of the offset center. Does anyone know of a way to get the center of the map with padding taken into account the same way that setCenter does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was to use Mapbox's [unproject](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#unproject) method. I first obtained the x/y screen coordinates of the offset map center, converted them to a mapbox [Point](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/geography/#point) object, and then used unproject to get that latitude and longitude at that location.

```js
const point = new mapboxgl.Point(screenX, screenY);
const latLng = map.unproject(point);
```